# Is it impossible to measure the strength of an electric field in quantum electrodynamics?

Tags: electromagnetism, quantum-field-theory, quantum-electrodynamics, education

I read that in quantum field theory, in particular in quantum electrodynamics, concepts such as the strength of an electric field or magnetic induction lose their meaning and cannot be measured. The electromagnetic potential also loses its physical meaning. And the only thing that has a physical meaning is the quantities directly related to the excitations of quantum fields (for example, the energy and momentum of a photon, and so on). How is it that in classical physics the electric field strength is observed, but in quantum theory it is not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a wrong information. In QED there are classical sources, like classical currents, that create the so called coherent states of photons, which are classical electromagnetic fields. What is different in QED is that when the electromagnetic field intensity is very small, we have "single photon regime" that gives different results. It is like a pressure - when the number of gas molecules is huge, the notion of pressure is meaningful, but when the nubmer of gas molecules is small, the wall experiences single hits rather than a constant pressure.

Comment: That is, the electric field strength is a coherent state of photons?

Comment: Yes, it is a coherent state of photons. The number of photons is uncertain, but the wave phase may be certain..

Comment: And what does the electromagnetic potential correspond to?

Comment: The electromagnetic potential is an operator (or a function, if you like) determined by the corresponding equation of motion (similar to the Classical Electrodynamics). It is gauge-dependent and is different for different particular cases. You may encounter a Coulomb potential and a plane wave (photon) potential.